# Localised date without year

Tags: ios, objective-c

In iOS I can format a date for the system locale. Is it possible to format a date for the system locale but excluding the year, e.g. say '7/17' for Europa and '17/7' for US?

**EDIT**

I'm doing this at present

```
        df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

        df.locale = NSLocale.systemLocale;
        [df setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate:@"MMMMd"];
```

but wondering if there is an equivalent to getting e.g. the short- or long formatted date BUT without the year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

recognize the difference between `NSLocale.systemLocale` and `NSLocale.currentLocale`. 
First one is general system format, last one is following the users settings. so your date formatter `NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];` is sensitive to what format you refer to.

the following should output the short formatted day and month = `Jul 17`.

```
df.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale;
[df setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate:@"dMMM"];
NSLog(@"%@",[df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

this should output the long formatted day and month = `July 17`.
`dd` means also day with leading zero i.e. `07` for the 7th day of month.

```
df.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale;
[df setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate:@"ddMMMM"];
NSLog(@"%@",[df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

but *systemLocale* is different. It will output = `07-17`.

```
df.locale = NSLocale.systemLocale;
[df setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate:@"ddMM"];
NSLog(@"%@",[df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

and even more fun and maybe what you are looking for. output = `07/17`.

```
df.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale;
[df setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate:@"ddMM"];
//[df setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate:@"MMdd"]; // sorting does'nt matter
NSLog(@"%@",[df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

Comment: haha. yes working hard for the next badge. :) chears